# Error 500.19 in server with IIS 10

Tags: iis, deployment, iis-10, net

I had a Web Service running in net 3.5 (I know, so old) and I migrate it to Net 4.6. I completed the migration in local, but when I deploy the web services in the server I get an 500.19 error. I review the log event, the traces, web.config... but I can´t figure out. Please, could you help me? Please, ask me for any extra information that you need as logs, traces, specifications, web.config,....
Many Thanks

REQUEST TRACE FAILED

```
<failedRequest url="https://webservices.XXXXXXXX.com:443/PRoject/Project.svc/get/?number=12345678"
               siteId="1570333581"
               appPoolId="webservices_apppool"
               processId="2644"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500.19"
               triggerStatusCode="500.19"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-05-31T11:54:31.713Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="2644" ThreadID="3212"/>
  <Computer>hostname</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="SiteId">1570333581</Data>
  <Data Name="AppPoolId">webservices_apppool</Data>
  <Data Name="ConnId">1610612819</Data>
  <Data Name="RawConnId">0</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestURL">https://webservices.XXXXX.com:443/Project/Project.svc/get/?number=12345678</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestVerb">GET</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: There should be an HRESULT code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps /iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for your help. In the event viewer don´t exist anything relevant. Just something about Perf Net. In the request trace of the server there are plenty of information. I posted something that I think could be interesting, but if you want to help me I can post more. But I can´t find anything related with HRESULT. Thanks again